# Linking Chart to Event in another Windows Form

Tags: c#, charts

I am developing my first C# Application and using MDI as my main menu. I have created two charts on the MDI Form - a pie chart to compare number of Female to Male Counselees, and a column chart to compare number of Female to Male counselors. Both charts are linked to the database. Effectively, I am doing the same comparison for two groups of people using two different charts (just testing my knowledge since this is my first Application).

My problem is this; whenever I setup a new counselee or counselor, my charts don't update/refresh automatically. I always have to exit and relaunch the application in order to see the updated status.

Can someone please help me? Attached is a screenshot of my application.
[Screenshot of my Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pErvO.png)

Comment: Did you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.selectevent.aspx ?

Comment: How do you connect the charts with the database? Does _whenever I setup a new counselee or counselor_ mean whenever you store them in the DB? You probably need to repeat one or more steps of what you do in the startup of your application..

Comment: I use databinding to link the chart to the database. Yes. Whenever I save new counselee to the database, my other reports are updated, but the charts don't until I log out and log in to the application again.